# Implementing google maps with react

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

React newbie here, please bear with me : ) Hopefully this will be very simple to solve

For the moment, I am simply trying to get the map to appear on screen, but when I run the code, the page is completely blank, and even my other divs do not appear. Here is my code, put in a gist: https://gist.github.com/JoeyBodnar/f76c5d434d57c6cc6108513ad79d4cb7

A few things to note: 1) from project directory, i already ran npm install --save react-google-maps 2) the code to make the map appear is taken from here: https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps

so what exactly am I doing wrong? is my declaration of "const GettingStartedGoogleMap" in the wrong place? or am I doing something wrong in the div?

also note, if I remove all google maps related code from that file, everything works as normal.

any help is appreciated, thanks

Edit, here is my code, still showing blank screen even hard coding height:

```
 return (
     <GettingStartedGoogleMap
 containerElement={
    <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />
 }
 mapElement={
 <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />
 }
 onMapLoad={_.noop}
 onMapClick={_.noop}
 markers={markers}
 onMarkerRightClick={_.noop}
/>
  );
```

Comment: Have you got some console errors ? A snippet could be a must

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is an improved version of my previous answer*

I've just tested your code, which contains lots of errors, undefined and unused variables!
Therefore, you can use the following code instead, which is quite simple (this will let you through the current problem and show the map!)

First, install necessary libraries:

```
npm install --save google-map-react
npm install --save prop-types
```

Then, you may copy the whole thing below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMapReact
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        style={{height: '300px'}}
      >
        <AnyReactComponent
          lat={59.955413}
          lng={30.337844}
          text={'Google Map'}
        />
      </GoogleMapReact>
    );
  }
}
MyClass.defaultProps = {
  center: {lat: 59.95, lng: 30.33},
  zoom: 11
};

export default MyClass;
```

Comment: You can also use the solution in my previous answer for setting map-height dynamically. I also suggest you read some document about React Component Life Cycle: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Comment: Hey Can you provide a sample code for adding Markers dynamically, with a Image.. If Could I'll be very thankfull to you!

Comment: @HelpingHand you may try: (change only 1 line) `const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div><img src="YOUR-IMG-SRC" className="YOUR-IMG-CLASS" /></div>;` You can also add style in the react's way like: `style={{width: '100px', height: '100px',}}` If this works for you, please consider give me an up-vote too, thanks

Comment: @thinhvo0108 That solved Adding Image! But can you give me a example how to add markers dynamically? Or I'll ask a question on that and send you the link? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey @thinhvo0108 Here is the Link..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937887/dynamically-adding-markers-on-react-google-map

Answer (score 2):

set height of the `<div style={{ height: 400px }} />` in pixels.

```
    <GettingStartedGoogleMap
     containerElement={
        <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />
   }
   mapElement={
     <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />
   }
   onMapLoad={_.noop}
   onMapClick={_.noop}
   markers={markers}
   onMarkerRightClick={_.noop}
  />
```

Answer (score 2):

npm modules like `google-map-react`

while debugging it all the divs are in absolute position

```css
  width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  position: relative;
```

will fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

The fact is: GoogleMap requires the length of element is correctly set before being rendered!
Therefore, you can either:

- Set a static height for your map element: (line 62)

  ```
  mapElement={
    <div style={{ height: `300px` }} />
  }
  ```

  OR
- use script to set it dynamically after the page has been loaded:

  ```
  componentDidMount() {
      console.log("component is mounted");
      this.setState({
        pageHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight + 'px'
      });
  }
  ...
  mapElement={
    <div style={{ height: this.state.pageHeight }} />
  }
  ```

Sorry I don't have enough time for testing your code, I can see the problem based on my own experience! So if the map doesn't show up yet, please feel free to set the height in pixel for your "containerElement" element, too!

**EDITED VERSION BELOW:**

*Please read the new answer of mine*

Comment: I have tried that, but still the page renders a blank white screen, see my edit.

Comment: I have just posted new edit, would you mind trying that again.
Besides, if possible, please show me some errors in case the code doesn't work yet! (maybe you still need to install some missing react libraries or so)

Comment: Sorry I've just added another edit: "npm install --save prop-types"
It seems that the GoogleMap library I used in that example requires that library, so feel free to install it, too!