# How to incorporate <script> in React to add Google Maps instance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, web, google-maps-api-3

**Than you very much to [thinhvo0108](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7318933/thinhvo0108) for showing how this can be implemented using [google-map-react](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react). His answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43600158/4955969).**

**However although this does solve my problem, my original question remains. Imagine there was no react component created that takes away the hassle of using `<script>`, how would I then implement Google Maps using the scripts as shown in the question below. In other words, how can one implement pure javascript scripts in the form `<script>` using React (ES6/ES7)**

I am working on adding a Google maps in my web application. I found this great generator [here](https://toolki.com/en/google-maps/) and it gave me this code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Google Maps</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:300px;"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            initialize();
        };

        function initialize() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.3419169876, 5.60793614352);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "Someplace"
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: "Someplace"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I take the scripts and paste them in my index.html file. The Google maps instance is supposed to be placed on the contact page. Obviously when I reload the page on /contact, I get the map loaded quickly. However since window is outside the scope in react, whenever I just navigate using my navbar, it does not work.

I have this GoogleMaps.js component which only contains the div of id map_canvas:

```
import React from 'react'

const GoogleMapsInstance = () => (
  <div id="map_canvas" style={{ width: '100%', height: '400px', overflow: 'hidden' }} />
)
export default GoogleMapsInstance
```

I was wondering how I could get the scripts inside this component, so I could call the scripts on componentDidMount function or something like that.

I am also open to any other type of solution that gets me a fast loading (no iframe) google maps :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way is not complicated, for your preference, I just posted yesterday and it works!

[Implementing google maps with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580092/implementing-google-maps-with-react/43581921#43581921)

If you want to add this map element onto your component or vice versa, please let me know!

EDITED VERSION BELOW (BASED ON YOUR NEED):

You can just follow this guide to make the map appear on your contact page:

First, install necessary libraries:

```
npm install --save google-map-react
npm install --save prop-types
```

Then, you may copy the whole thing below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMapReact
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        style={{width: '500px', height: '300px'}}
      >
        <AnyReactComponent
          lat={50.3419169876}
          lng={5.60793614352}
          text={'MY SHOP'}
        />
      </GoogleMapReact>
    );
  }
}
MyClass.defaultProps = {
  center: {lat: 50.34, lng: 5.61},
  zoom: 16
};

export default MyClass;
```

Feel free to edit the LatLng value, and/or "MY SHOP" text, I believe you can also use some custom PNG image instead of text-element to show your preferred map-pin representing your shop

Comment: Thanks! Got this working now. You're right that the 'marker' can be customized, which is nice considering I don't only want text as it looks quite bland.

Comment: Glad you made it, pal ^^ !

Answer (score 0):

Simple search on Google ;)

Try :  https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps

Demo : https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/

Comment: I found that, but it seems unnecessarily complicated, and I had trouble implementing it.

Comment: Show me your react main render code (component) then i could help you ;)