# Google Map is taking up entire screen

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I am using a library, google-map-react: https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react

I have followed the instructions in the readme and the map appears on screen, but it takes up the entire screen by default, and i can't get it to change. Here is my code. I have tried:

```
 <GoogleMapReact
    defaultCenter={this.props.center}
    defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
    style={{height: '400px', width: '400px'}}
  >
```

and

```
<GoogleMapReact
    defaultCenter={this.props.center}
    defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
    size={{height: '400px', width: '400px'}}
  >
```

and

```
 <GoogleMapReact
    defaultCenter={this.props.center}
    defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
    style={height: '400px', width: '400px'}
  >
```

and I have also tried using percents instead of hard coding pixels. The documentation doesn't say anything about how to set the size, how can I do that? I even tried putting it inside a  (from bootstrap) and it still takes up the entire area. How can I manually set the size?

Comment: This is weird, would you mind posting your code, also some CSS rules applied on the page. Perhaps your map-container's width is overwritten by width 100% somewhere from parent-DOM, I just guess so

Answer (score 1):

The documentation here:

- https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react/blob/master/DOC.md

gives an example, although it isn't obvious to me how you pass that to the GoogleMapReact tag:

```
{
  center: { lat, lng }, // current map center
  zoom: 4, // current map zoom
  bounds: { nw, se, sw... }, // map corners in lat lng
  size: { width, height... } // map size in px
}
```

There's also this example:

- https://jsbin.com/roqutisoqu/1/edit?js,console,output

where the width and height are supplied as inline styles on the div the map gets rendered in:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div style={{width: '100%', height: 400}}>
    <SimpleMap/>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem which have now been fixed at my end after reading the [documentation](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/DOC.md) thoroughly. The documentation says:

> By default map will not raise onChange event if parent size has changed, to change such behavior add resetBoundsOnResize = {true} property.

I just added the attribute `resetBoundsOnResize = {true}` in `GoogleMapReact` as below:

```
<GoogleMapReact
    resetBoundsOnResize={true}
    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "your api key" }}
    defaultCenter={location}
    defaultZoom={zoomLevel}
  >
```

And the map is now rendering inside the parent.

Comment: I get an error `Type '{ resetBoundsOnResize: boolean; mapContainerStyle: { width: string; height: string; }; center: { lat: any; lng: any; }; zoom: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<GoogleMap> & Readonly<GoogleMapProps> & Readonly<...>'.`

Answer (score 0):

It's important where you put your GoogleMapReact component, because the size (width) of the container is important

Please also refer to this answer of mine, which is using the same library: 
[Implementing google maps with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580092/implementing-google-maps-with-react/43581921#43581921)

In your case here, you may use the following code: (using another DIV as a wrapper with width & height set as you prefer)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{height: '400px', width: '400px'}}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          defaultCenter={this.props.center}
          defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
          style={{height: '400px', width: '400px'}}
        >
          <AnyReactComponent
            lat={59.955413}
            lng={30.337844}
            text={'Google Map'}
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
MyClass.defaultProps = {
  center: {lat: 59.95, lng: 30.33},
  zoom: 11
};

export default MyClass;
```