# Dynamically Adding Markers on google-map-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

What I wan't to do is to show the location picked from some mobile devices on the Map.
Data about the locations are there..

What I need here is to add Markers on the map depending on the data received from the server.

Assume I have set the location data **({Lat,Lang})** to the **state markers** 
Then How can I add this to show in Map.

My Map Code is as follows!

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMapReact
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        style={{height: '300px'}}
      >
        <AnyReactComponent
          lat={59.955413}
          lng={30.337844}
          text={'Google Map'}
        />
      </GoogleMapReact>
    );
  }
}
MyClass.defaultProps = {
  center: {lat: 59.95, lng: 30.33},
  zoom: 11
};

export default MyClass;
```

This Code is from the answer [Implementing google maps with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580092/implementing-google-maps-with-react)

Used npm package :- google-map-react

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const AnyReactComponent = ({  img_src }) => <div><img src={img_src} className="YOUR-CLASS-NAME" style={{}} /></div>;

class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        markers: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    // or you can set markers list somewhere else
    // please also set your correct lat & lng
    // you may only use 1 image for all markers, if then, remove the img_src attribute ^^
    this.setState({
      markers: [{lat: xxxx, lng: xxxx, img_src: 'YOUR-IMG-SRC'},{lat: xxxx, lng: xxxx, img_src: 'YOUR-IMG-SRC' },{lat: xxxx, lng: xxxx,  img_src: 'YOUR-IMG-SRC'}],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMapReact
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        style={{height: '300px'}}
      >
            {this.state.markers.map((marker, i) =>{
              return(
                <AnyReactComponent
                  lat={marker.lat}
                  lng={marker.lng}
                  img_src={marker.img_src}
                />

              )
            })}      
      </GoogleMapReact>
    );
  }
}
MyClass.defaultProps = {
  center: {lat: 59.95, lng: 30.33},
  zoom: 11
};
```

If this has error, please show here too, then we can fix it later

===========

**ADDED EXAMPLE FOR CLICK-EVENT ON MARKERS**

```
 markerClicked(marker) {
   console.log("The marker that was clicked is", marker);
   // you may do many things with the "marker" object, please see more on tutorial of the library's author:
  // https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react/blob/master/API.md#onchildclick-func 
  // Look at their examples and you may have some ideas, you can also have the hover effect on markers, but it's a bit more complicated I think 
 }

 render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMapReact
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        style={{height: '300px'}}
      >
            {this.state.markers.map((marker, i) =>{
              return(
                <AnyReactComponent
                  lat={marker.lat}
                  lng={marker.lng}
                  img_src={marker.img_src}
                  onChildClick={this.markerClicked.bind(this, marker)}
                />

              )
            })}      

      </GoogleMapReact>
    );
  }
```

Once again, post here some errors if any ^^ !

Comment: No Error It Works! But, Image Doesn't appear! Just a square. In the Image property class I should enter as png/jpg/ico am I Right?

Comment: Did you inspect those "square" images to check their url, maybe their src is invalid ^^ ? Besides, please just use img's valid url, don't add png/ico or anything ^^ className here in jsx just means their CSS class (you may just leave it blank like className="") thanks

Comment: Yes! It was problem with source!!.. Can you give me one last help?

Comment: If I wan't to get the onTap event of the marker! How should I proceed? Thanks a lot Buddy! You saved me days of work!

Comment: You're welcome ^^ ! Actually, the above answer is just a very simple example of GoogleMap for react. The library we're using is used for rendering react-component on the map, which is useful for server-side rendering, therefore, the tap-event for marker will be a bit more complicated. I will show you some demo on how to implement tap-event now, but if you truly want to have full features with more "natural"
 googlemap (markers + events, polylines, directions etc.), you may consider using another powerful library: https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps

Comment: Thanks a lot Buddy, you save my day!! :)

Comment: I tried to use that library, But I can.t understand the way it's example code is written. But Your one is straight forward( You have written it with classes & example in the tomchentw uses const)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you had it working. However, the click or hover function for the current library on Markers should be implemented more ^^ Try your best!

Comment: I am not able to trigger the click event on click of marker. Please suggest

Comment: @thinhvo0108 if you get chance to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62644430/how-to-click-on-markers-in-google-map-react I need some help here, can't seem to get it to work

Comment: @RedBaron I answered

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. You said `react-google-map` but you are using `google-map-react`. Those are 2 different packages. Do not mix up their documentation.

Comment: Link does not work for me. Gives a 404. Maybe it's a private repository. :)