# How to add marker on map by Click using react-google-maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I'm struggling to find a very simple example of how to add a marker(s) to a Google Map when a user left clicks on the map using React-google-maps in components based. Need help.

```
const Map = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={8}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
    onClick = {props.onMapClick}
   >
  {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={props.markerPosition} />}

 </GoogleMap>
))

export default class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {

   }
 }

render () {
  return (
  <div style={{height: '100%'}}>
    <Map
      googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC4R6AN7SmujjPUIGKdyao2Kqitzr1kiRg&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
      loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
      mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      placeMarker={this.placeMarker}
    />
  </div>
)
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a generic example that demonstrates how to display marker on map click:

```
const Map = compose(
    withStateHandlers(() => ({
        isMarkerShown: false,
        markerPosition: null
      }), {
        onMapClick: ({ isMarkerShown }) => (e) => ({
            markerPosition: e.latLng,
            isMarkerShown:true
        })
      }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)
    (props =>
        <GoogleMap
            defaultZoom={8}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
            onClick={props.onMapClick}
        >
            {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={props.markerPosition} />}

        </GoogleMap>
    )

export default class MapContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
                <Map
                    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC4R6AN7SmujjPUIGKdyao2Kqitzr1kiRg&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
                    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-umnzy4)

Comment: ```e.latLng``` of Marker is a function. If I want to access the ```latLng.lat``` itself, how can I do so.
For example, If I want to render the Lat and lng on the screen, how can I do that?

Comment: and to give myself an answer (and to all interested)
```e.latLng.lat().toFixed(3)``` does the trick

Answer (score 3):

Check this code with the edited version which add the marker

```
const InitialMap = withGoogleMap(props => {
  var index = this.marker.index || [];

  return(
    <GoogleMap
      ref={props.onMapLoad}
      zoom={13}
      center={{ lat: 21.178574, lng: 72.814149 }}
      onClick={props.onMapClick}
    >
      {props.markers.map(marker => (
        <Marker
          {...marker}
          onRightClick={() => props.onMarkerRightClick(marker)}
        />
      ))}
    </GoogleMap>
  )
});

export default class MapContainer extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      markers:[{
        position:{
          lat: 255.0112183,
          lng:121.52067570000001,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div style={{height:"100%"}}>
        <InitialMap
          containerElement={
            <div style={{height:"150px"}}/>
          }
          mapElement={
            <div style={{height:"150px"}} />
          }
          markers={this.state.markers} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Arthi, where is the function onMapClick

Comment: @Van can you check this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937887/dynamically-adding-markers-on-react-google-map